# Python Pillow resize images trouble: it runs well but there're no images

Tags: python, resize, batch-processing, python-imaging-library, save-image

I'm learning Python and try to use Pillow to resize images in a folder, then save them to another folder with the same filename. However, the program runs well, when I check the destination folder, there're no images... 
My code is as below:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, glob, sys

src_path = "D:/Test_A/src/*.png"
dst_path = "D:/Test_A/dst/"
img_list = glob.glob(src_path)

for XXPNG in img_list:
    fn = os.path.basename(XXPNG)
    im = Image.open(XXPNG)
    print(fn, im.size)
    nim = im.resize((119, 119), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    nim.save("dst_path","PNG")
print("Resize Done")
```

Please help me find my bug, or give my any advise.
Thank you very much for help and bearing my poor English.

Comment: you forgot extension in filename `save("dst_path.png","PNG")`

Comment: `"dst_path"` in your `save()` is a normal text, not variable `dst_path`. You need `dst_path` without `"` and filename - `nim.save(dst_path + fn, "PNG")`

Answer (score 1):

`"dst_path"` with `"` is a normal text, not variable `dst_path` - so you save in file with name `"dst_path"`.

You need `dst_path` without `"` - plus filename

```
nim.save(dst_path + fn, "PNG")
```

or with `os.path.join()`

```
nim.save(os.path.join(dst_path, name), "PNG")
```

Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, glob, sys

src_path = "D:/Test_A/src/*.png"
dst_path = "D:/Test_A/dst/"
img_list = glob.glob(src_path)

for fullpath in img_list:
    name = os.path.basename(fullpath)
    im = Image.open(fullpath)

    print(name, im.size, '=>', os.path.join(dst_path, name))

    nim = im.resize((119, 119), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    nim.save(os.path.join(dst_path, name), "PNG")
    #nim.save(dst_path + name, "PNG")

print("Resize Done")
```